# Reduce gap between Report Footer and Page Footer

Tags: crystal-reports

There is a sizable gap between report footer and page footer. How can I reduce the blank space?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the section expert, you'll note that the Page Footer has *Print at Bottom of Page* checked, and is grayed out. A page footer will always print at the bottom of the page.

If you want to move the Report Footer *down* you can check *Print at Bottom of Page* for both of them.

If you want to move the Page Footer *up* it's a little trickier. You might get by with suppressing the Page Footer on the last page only, and displaying a duplicate section at the end of the report (if there's more than one page.) This should handle both large and small page counts.